# ObjectDisposeException when navigating through forms c#

Tags: c#, forms, navigation

I have wanted to navigate through forms so when I client the buttonKlient I go to the Form2 then when I click control 'x' I go back to Form1 I got:

(the `fk` is `Form2`)

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                if (fk == null)
                    fk = new OknoKlient();
                fk.Tag = this;
                fk.Show(this);//here is ObjectDisposedException
                Hide();
            }
```

Then in `Form2`

```
 protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;
            var form1 = (Form1)Tag;
            form1.Show();
            Hide();
            // DO WHATEVER HERE
        }
```

When I click `button1` the `Form2 fk` opens, then I close it by `x` control then click the button1 again and I get the exception `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: @gdoron I am sorry I got StackOverflow when I had Close(); instead of Hide() in the OnFormClosing method.

Comment: Are you using two different ids? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419182/how-to-override-closing-control-in-windows-form-c-sharp#14419262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;
    e.Cancel = true; // <---------------------- this
    var form1 = (Form1)Tag;
    form1.Show();
    Hide();
    // DO WHATEVER HERE
}
```

You're hiding the form yes.. but the form is still being disposed. You need to add `e.Cancel = true;` to cancel the form closing.